# E, Z designation - what to do when substituents are identical on one side of the double bond?

Tags: nomenclature, stereochemistry

[image]

Here, A has a greater atomic number than B, which has a greater atomic number than C. To assign E,Z designations you would divide the double bond into left and right portions and assign priorities. On the right side, A > C. However, on the left side, B = B. A (first priority on right side) is simultaneously on the same side and on opposite sides to B (first priority on left side). How would you class this compound then?

Comment: How would you classify an ethylene molecule _without_ any substituents? Is it E or Z?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I take it that you mean E,Z nomenclature can permissibly fail to class a molecule?

Comment: How would you classify a _methane_ molecule without any substituents and without any double bonds? Is it E or Z?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I thought that E,Z nomenclature was used for compounds with double/triple bonds.

Comment: That's right (that is, if you throw away the triple bonds), but there's a catch. First and foremost, **any** nomenclature (not just E,Z) exists to tell apart _different_ things. Your molecule is _identical_, no matter which way you orient those A and C. There is nothing to tell apart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When both the substituents are identical on one side of the double bond, the compound does not show geometrical isomerism.**

There is no point in using E-Z nomenclature in that case.